# Word Macro renaming file from excel sheet while printing as PDF

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have setup a mail merge to draft letters based on input from Excel sheet.
Post draft completion. I have Word VBA code to print each page as PDF.
Currently it asks me save folder and file name to be entered manually. How can I incorporate Folder location and filename to be picked from excelsheet in the below code :

```
Sub Print_letter()
Dim x As Long, StrPrtr As String
StrPrtr = Application.ActivePrinter
Application.ActivePrinter = "microsoft print to pdf"
With ActiveDocument
  For x = 1 To .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
    Application.PrintOut PrintToFile:=False, FileName:="", _
      Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:=CStr(x), Item:=wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, _
      Background:=True, PageType:=wdPrintAllPages, Copies:=1, Collate:=False, _
      PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
  Next x
End With
Application.ActivePrinter = StrPrtr
End Sub
```

Comment: What are your expectations when use `FileName:=""`? Do you work in Word VBA and want " filename to be picked from excelsheet? Do you want an automation to take pieces of information from Excel, or what?

Comment: @FaneDuru `FileName:="Workbook.Sheetname.Cells(F, 2).Value` starts from range F2 and should loop though till the data ends

Comment: @FaneDuru FileName:="Workbook.Sheetname.Cells(F, 2).Value . Yes from Excel range starts from F2 and should loop though till the end of data in column F

Comment: And what don't you know doing? To access an existing Excel session and set a specific workbook, followed by sheet and range? Is this the problem you try putting in discussion? If yes, and you answer in a reasonable period of time, I can show you how to accomplish that...

Comment: could you tell me your availability, any time window and time zone

Comment: Now it is 09:47 AM. Until 17:00 I may be available, but not all the time. But your problem does not require too much time to be spent, I think... Did you understand the code I posted like an answer? Do you know how to iterate between the range cells and use their value? If not, I can show it. I will adapt the testing procedure in a way to make it iterate between all cells in the range and return their value in Immediate Window. Do you know how to acces this Immediate Window?

Comment: Adapted the answer code as I said in the above comment. Please, test the solution I tried providing and send some feedback. If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. But, if hours will pass until your replay, I am afraid that my enthusiasm will not stay at a very high level...

Comment: I am going to try your code, Yes I know how to access Immediate Window? I am at work as well :)

Comment: i understand what u mean. I am setting aside time for this.  getting free in 15 mins

Comment: Hi can we move this session to Chat

Comment: To access an existing Excel session and set a specific workbook, followed by sheet and range?  - Yes.     Do you know how to iterate between the range cells and use their value?  - NO

Comment: Getting compile error "User-defined type not defined" on `Function getRangefromExcelSession(strWorkbook As String, strSheet As String) As Excel.Range`

Comment: But the updated code shows you how to do it. The cells value is returned in Immediate Window...

Comment: Did you add a reference to 'Microsoft Excel   Object Library' as was stated in the code...? Do you know how to do that? Did you add any (new) reference until now?

Comment: Yes added Microsoft Excel Object Library' from the ref lib

Comment: Restarted word file. Can see the range value in immediate window now

Comment: How do I incorporate this in my code to pick each value when printing each page and saving in a folder location

Comment: Do you want to use the next range value for each saving? Do the cell values contain the path and pdf extension? Please, show me how such a cell value looks.

Comment: Yes. when I am printing Page 1 to pdf , I want to pick the file name frm excel F2 (first range) and save to C:\, then move to Page 2 and F3 and so on. Cell values do not contain .pdf extns

Comment: So, the correct answer should be: No, there no any path and extension in the cell value... Is this understanding correct?

Comment: If my above understanding is correct, I will edit my answer and add your code, adapted to do what (I understood) you need...

Comment: Please, test the updated code and send some feedback. But not here, please comment on my answer...

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Then, please test the code I posted after editing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say anything and I must leave my office...

Please, try the next code, able to define a range of an Excel workbook:

```
'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Excel ... Object library'
Function getRangefromExcelSession(strWorkbook As String, strSheet As String) As Excel.Range
  Dim Ex As Excel.Application, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, rng As Range
  Dim wbFound As Workbook, Boolfound As Boolean, lastRow As Long
  
   On Error Resume Next
    Set Ex = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
        For Each wb In Ex.Workbooks
            If wb.Name = strWorkbook Then
                Set wbFound = wb
                Boolfound = True
            End If
        Next
     Else
       On Error GoTo 0
       MsgBox "There is not any Excel session open...", vbInformation, "Ups...": Exit Function
     End If
     If Boolfound Then
        Set ws = wbFound.Worksheets(strSheet)
        lastRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
        Set getRangefromExcelSession = ws.Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
     End If
End Function
```

It is not provided with error handling in case of no (your) workbook/sheet found...

The necessary range can be obtained in this way:

```
Sub testBetRangeFromExcelSess()
    Dim rng As Excel.Range, cel As Range
    Set rng = getRangefromExcelSession("Your workbook name", "Your sheet name")
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print rng.Address
        For Each cel In rng
            Debug.Print cel.Value
        Next
    End IfWindow
End Sub
```

**Edited:**

Your adapted code should look like this:

```
Sub Print_letter()
Dim x As Long, StrPrtr As String
StrPrtr = Application.ActivePrinter
Application.ActivePrinter = "microsoft print to pdf"

Dim rng As Excel.Range
Set rng = getRangefromExcelSession("Workbook name", "sheet name")

With ActiveDocument
  For x = 1 To .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
    Application.PrintOut PrintToFile:=False, OutputFileName:="C:\" & rng(x, 1).Value & ".pdf", _
      Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:=CStr(x), Item:=wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, _
      background:=True, PageType:=wdPrintAllPages, Copies:=1, Collate:=False, _
      PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
  Next x
End With
Application.ActivePrinter = StrPrtr
End Sub
```

**Second edit**:

Please, try running the next testing code:

```
Sub testPrintToPdf_() 
 Dim StrPrtr As String, x As Long
 StrPrtr = Application.ActivePrinter
 Application.ActivePrinter = "microsoft print to pdf"
 
 With ActiveDocument
    For x = 1 To .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
        Application.PrintOut PrintToFile:=False, OutputFileName:="C:\testdDoc_" & x & ".pdf", _
          Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:=CStr(x), Item:=wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, _
          Background:=True, PageType:=wdPrintAllPages, Copies:=1, Collate:=False, _
          PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
    Next x
 End With
End Sub
```

It should return 15 documents named as "testDoc_1,pdf", "testDoc_2,pdf" and so on...

Comment: getting an Run time error 5174 on save .says couldn't find your file. its deleted or moved ? "C:\ABCD.pdf"

Comment: @user9630941: Did you test your code without the file name supplied by the code, bringing the values from the Excel sheet? **Is it a working piece of code**? I only supplied an answer to your question, as it has been formulated...

Comment: @user9630941: Please, try the updated code. I am afraid that you used `FileName` instead of `OutputFileName`...

Comment: Oh ok let me try that

Comment: Work Like a charm.!!! Thanks so much. So much of manual work is gone. Really appreciate you time and effort. Thanks again

Comment: @user9630941:  Glad I could help!

Comment: I did some checks, code prints the 1 page  fine, but the second output prints all pages together in one file. Eg. I have 15 letters. the code separates and prints letter 1 as one pdf. from letter 2 -15 its prints in signle PDF. Hope I am making sense

Comment: @user9630941:  I do not even know what `.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)` means... I usually avoid using Word. What are they? Can you manually print those `wdStatisticPages`? If yes, how many pages are printed?

Comment: `.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)` this to count the number of pages in the  word document and then printing 1 page as 1 pdf so in this case 15 pdfs should be printed.  count of page is proportional to the file name that we are getting from excel column F in this case 15.

Comment: I made some researches on the issue which was unknown for me. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.computestatistics?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbawd10.chm158007414);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) Microsoft explains what is it about. What are your expectations, from this point of view? What does the code return in the pages saved as pdf? I suppose it prints the document pages. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user9630941: So, do you want printing each document page on a pdf file? Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct. My word file as of now has 15 pages (which varies case to case basis). Objective here is to Print each PAGE as 1 PDF . so final output in folder would be 15 PDF

Comment: @user9630941: Try the updated code, please.

Comment: @user9630941: Saying only that, without telling on which code line the error appears, is useless...

Comment: Update the number of pages and code executed but same issue, page 1 prints fine. page 2-15 are combined in 1 pdf as before

Comment: How many pdf documents are produced by the code? Try putting a break point of the line  `Application.PrintOut...` and then press F8 to run line by line. How  many times the iteration works? Having `CStr(x)` it should produce as many pages as the document has...

Comment: Sure let me check,  How many pdf documents are produced by the code?  - right now only 2

Comment: Same only 2 pdf. Page 1 and page 2-15 in 2nd pdf. Although i checked value of x at each iteration it is going up to 15 as specified but no relavent output as such

Comment: @user9630941:  Very strange... If you try printing the document on an ordinary printer, how many pages will result? I tested a similar code now, on my computer and it prints  (to pdf) exactly how many pages the document has. If  not something confidential, can you share the document in discussion? So, in conclusion, the iteration works 15 times, but even if it is a `PrintOut` line, it does not work. Is this what I have to understand?

Comment: Unfortunately i cant share the document,  So, in conclusion, the iteration works 15 times, but even if it is a PrintOut line, it does not work. Is this what I have to understand? –  Thats correct .. very strange indeed. I need individual document in PDF format ultimately.

Comment: @user9630941:  Like I told you, I do not use Word very often. Now I created a test piece of code which works as it should. I do not know what is happening in your case. Maybe to share the code to try it, too... Did it. Please, try it and send some feedback.

Comment: Figured . it was due to the page break. Thanks again